# Random timer windows on a DC circuit

Tags: dc, timer, random

Are there any components/devices out there (available via RadioShack, or some other vendor) that behave as follows (or similarly):

1. When a signal/voltage is detected, a random (and preferably configurable) timer begins. My desired "random" time range is between 1 and 4 seconds; then
2. After this random 1 - 4 second timer/window elapses, this device places a signal/voltage on an outbound wire

**Any components like this exist, or do you have to build up "random timers" from lots of smaller "subsystem"/constituent circuits/components?**

Comment: A 555 timer in astable configuration can do this, though it's not a random time

Comment: Sounds like the sort of thing where commercial applications would just use a cheap 8-bit microcontroller.  For the hobbyist, that would be an Arduino or similar.

Comment: Random? What's that now...